# How to assign a pull request using the REST API?

Tags: github, github-api

I'm creating a GitHub pull request using the appropriate [REST API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/pulls#create-a-pull-request). Specifying a single `assignee` or an `assignees` (using either the user `login` or GitHub's internal `id`) has no effect. The pull request will be created, but without an assignee set. There also seems to be no other endpoint to explicitly assign a pull request to a user. Now I'm wondering whether it's possible at all to set the assignee of a pull request using the REST API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Every pull request is an issue, but not every issue is a pull request.
> For this reason, "shared" actions for both features, like manipulating
> assignees, labels and milestones, are provided within the Issues API.
> From [PR Doc](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/issues/assignees#add-assignees-to-an-issue)

So, you can use [Add assignees to an issue](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/issues/assignees#add-assignees-to-an-issue) API to set an assignee(s) to a pull request After PR is created. You need to know its number, which is in the JSON body of Create Pull Request's response.

```
/repos/{owner}/{repo}/issues/{issue_number}/assignees
```

where `issue_number` is same as `pr_number`